# how to show dynamic column in datatable?

Tags: php, mysql, angular7

I have followed these link for data-table.

> http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way

Currently it is working fine when i am using static columns .

My requirement :-

I want to dynamic column in data-table

```
this.dtOptions = {
    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    pageLength: 4,
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
      that.http
        .post<DataTablesResponse>(
          'http://localhost/api/listregister.php',
          dataTablesParameters, {}
        ).subscribe(resp => {
          that.persons = resp.data;

          callback({
            recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
            recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
            data: []
          });
        });
    },
/this place i want to dynamic column/   columns: : [{ data: 'id' }, { data: 'firstName' }, { data: 'lastName' }]
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When i do console 
show array :-

Now it is working fine when this array is show

console.log(this.test) it is showing

```
0: {data: "id", mData: "id"}
1: {data: "firstname", mData: "firstname"}
2: {data: "lastname", mData: "lastname"}




ngOnInit(): void {
   const that = this;
   const columns_data = this.getContacts();

    this.test = this.persons;
    console.log(this.persons);
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 4,
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      searching: false,
      ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
        that.http
          .post<DataTablesResponse>(
            'http://localhost/api/listregister.php',
            dataTablesParameters, {}
          ).subscribe(resp => {
            that.persons = resp.data;

            callback({
              recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
              recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
              data: []
            });
          });
      },
    columns: this.test
    };
  }







  getContacts(): void {
  this.personService.getregistercolumns()
    .subscribe(
         persons => {
           persons.forEach((line, index) => {
              this.persons.push(line);
          });
      });
  }

}
```